# How to write the condition of " Given at least 1 child in the class is true / false, then..."?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

```
if( $('.adv').css('display') != 'none' )
{
    Navigation.closePopUp();
}
```

The problem is there are several child in this class, if **at least one child** in this class 's display css is not equal to none , than do something...

Is it possible to have this condition? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `visible` selector and `length` property.

```
if ( $('.adv:visible').length )
```

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Pseudo classes are something from the CSS, jQuery calls these Selectors. See [:visible Selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Comment: Yes, but they can be easily confused with CSS selectors, so it's best to just normalize it.